# Replace comma separated numbers with weekdays in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am saving the weekends in a table as 0,6 (for Sunday,Saturday) and weekdays like 1,4,6(for Monday,Thursday,Saturday). While selecting I need to replace the numbers with the appropriate weekdays. For example.,

```
SELECT WEEKEND_DAYS FROM TABLE_1
```

Returns

```
WEEKEND_DAYS
1,4,6
```

But I need the o/p as

```
WEEKEND_DAYS 
Monday,Thursday,Saturday
```

How to achieve this? Thanks in advance...

Comment: WARNING: You most likely have a data modelling issue. If you are building a new system, consider doing some research on normalising databases. If this is a 'mature' system that you can't change you're out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

Use ugly `REPLACE()` can do the job

```
SELECT
    WEEKEND_DAYS, 
    REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
    REPLACE(WEEKEND_DAYS 
    , 1, 'Monday') 
    , 2, 'Tuesday') 
    , 3, 'Wensday') 
    , 4, 'Thursday') 
    , 5, 'Friday') 
    , 6, 'Saturday') 
    , 0, 'Sunday') AS WEEKEND_DAYS_NAME
FROM (VALUES('1,4,6')) TABLE_1(WEEKEND_DAYS)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try following,

It will gives you 
6 = Sunday
0 = Monday

```
DECLARE  @daynum VARCHAR(256)
SET @daynum = '1,5,3,2'
IF @daynum = '' RETURN
      DECLARE @XML xml
      SET @XML = '<root><csv>'+replace(@daynum,',','</csv><csv>')+
                 '</csv></root>'

     Select STUFF(( SELECT ',' + dayname
     FROM   
     (          
      Select DATENAME(DW,CAST(ListMember AS INT)) as dayname from
      (
        SELECT rtrim(ltrim(replace(Word.value('.','nvarchar(max)'),char(10),'')))
             AS ListMember
        FROM @XML.nodes('/root/csv') AS WordList(Word)
       )T
      ) T2             
       ORDER BY dayname
       FOR XML PATH('')
      ), 1, 1, '')
```

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/2185)

You can also create split function then call it according to need.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnParseStringXML (
      @StringList NVARCHAR(MAX),
      @Delimiter CHAR(1))
RETURNS @TableList TABLE(ID int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
                         [Substring] NVARCHAR(max))
BEGIN
      IF @StringList = '' RETURN
      DECLARE @XML xml
      SET @XML = '<root><csv>'+replace(@StringList,@Delimiter,'</csv><csv>')+
                 '</csv></root>'
      INSERT @TableList
      SELECT rtrim(ltrim(replace(Word.value('.','nvarchar(max)'),char(10),'')))
             AS ListMember
      FROM @XML.nodes('/root/csv') AS WordList(Word)
RETURN
END -- FUNCTION
GO
```

And you should call it in that way.

```
Select DATENAME(DW,CAST(Substring AS INT)) from
(
    SELECT Substring FROM  dbo.fnParseStringXML  (@ProductCode, ',')
)T
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your first set of code giving the days in individual rows, I need it in comma separated. And the function which is returning the @Tablelist is passing two columns with the numbers only, not the weekdays, that to in separate rows, i need it in comma separated.

Comment: @Eric gave an easy solution for that, my aim is to give you another option to show you how you can deal with that kind of data. :)

Comment: By the way see the updated answer (first query) it will give you output as you want.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me. 
Hope it helps.
Use 1-7 for indexing days

```
<?php 
$result="";

// include("database.php");
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("db_name") or die(mysql_error());


$query= mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT weekend_days from weekend where weekend_days= '1,4,6'"));
if (!$query) {
    echo "No weekend";
}
else {
 $new= explode(",", $query[0]);
 for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($new) ; $i++) {
    if($new[$i]==1){
        $result.= " Sunday";
    }
    elseif($new[$i]==2) {
        $result.=", Monday";
    }
    elseif($new[$i]==3){
        $result.= ", Tuesday";
    }
    elseif($new[$i]==4){
        $result.= ", Wednesday";
    }
    elseif($new[$i]==5){
        $result.=", Thursday";
    }
    elseif($new[$i]==6){
        $result.= ", Friday";
    }
    elseif($new[$i]==7){
        $result.= ", Saturday";
    }
}
echo "WEEKEND_DAYS  " . $result;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
SELECT
    REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
    REPLACE(WEEKEND_DAYS
    , 1, 'Monday')
    , 2, 'Tuesday')
    , 3, 'Wednesday')
    , 4, 'Thursday')
    , 5, 'Friday')
    , 6, 'Saturday')
    , 0, 'Sunday') AS WEEKEND_DAYS_NAME
FROM  TABLE_1
```